# Image on hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is what I have:

```
.error
{
background: url(error.jpg) no-repeat right top;
}
```

and via JQuery I give or take the class "error" to a textbox. So, the textbox has the image as a background, but not the whole textbox, but only its right part. What I now want to make is on hover on the image (not the textbox) to show title of the image. How to add title to the image and how to make its on hover event?

Comment: how do you retrieve the image title? where it is stored?

Comment: @F.Calderan Well, nowhere. That's what I'm asking. How to give it?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you can't do that for css background image.

Comment: You could make a simple hack. For example placing a transparent picture where you want the hover-animation to trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the image is part of the background of the input, you can't attach events to it.

You can however place an `alt` or `title` attribute on the `input` itself which will act like a tooltip in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For hover you can use:

```
$('#myElement').hover( function () {/*in focus code */},
                       function () {/*out of focus code*/});
```

To determine if just that image has been hovered you'll need to attach to the mousemove event and get the mouse coords when over the element and work it out yourself. I'd store the current mouse coords after each mousemove event of your element and then in your hover functions determine if you are within the image area.

```
var currentMousePos;
$('#myElement').mousemove(function (event) {
  currentMousePos = {(event.pageX - $('#myElement').left), 
                     (event.pageY - $('#myElement').top)};
});
```

Comment: This is not as clean as other answers, but it does offer the functionality you desire, you'll have to weigh up the costs and benefits.